# How to locate sibling nodes with XPath

Tags: xpath

This is the experimental [web page address](https://book.douban.com/subject/2567698/)
Please take a look at the image below; this is the node I really want to capture. Because it is very similar to the previous node:

```
 <div class="indent" id="dir_2567698_short" style="display: none;">,
```

I used

```
 //*[contains(@class,'indent') and contains(@style,'display' )]/..
```

to find its parent node, and then used

```
/div[6]
```

to locate the actual target. However, the target node rankings may not always be in the 6th position; some may be in the 5th position. Therefore, I want to use

```
//*[contains(@class,'indent') and contains(@style,'display' )]/.
```

to first locate `<div class="indent" id="dir_2567698_short" style="display: none;">`. Then, I want to find **its next sibling node** at the same level, which will allow me to accurately find the target node. However, I have tried several methods without success. How can I find the 'next sibling node'?

Here are the methods I've tried but didn't work：

```
//*[contains(@class,'indent')and contains(@style,'display' )]/./div[1]
//*[contains(@class,'indent')and contains(@style,'display' )]/./div[0]
```

[image]

Comment: are these id's (`dir_2567698_short`) random ? or can you rely on them?

Comment: yes，different book different id，it is random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids in HTML are supposed to be unique so if you are looking for an element node with an `id` attribute like `<div class="indent" id="dir_2567698_short" style="display: none;">`, it seems `//*[@id = 'dir_2567698_short']` or, if the XPath implementation supports the `id` function for HTML, even `id('dir_2567698_short')` should suffice.

As for siblings, use `preceding-sibling::*[1]` or `following-sibling::*[1]`, to find the first preceding or following sibling element.

Comment: Different book different id，The id is random.

Comment: Thank you, the code runs smoothly and can locate the target node. May I ask how you learned XPath? Are there any books you would recommend on XPath?